How can I simulate pressing the letter Q in selenium?
I am not talking about entering the letter Q in any input field in selenium. In this case, it is enough to write element.send_keys(“Q”), but I need to trigger an event in the body of the web page. Normally when I press the letter Q on the web page, a new tab opens on the page. I need selenium to do this.
I tried everything but i didnt find any solving

Why would there be more than one way to simulate keypresses?  The answer is almost certainly .send_keys("Q"), just directed to the body of the page, rather than an input field.

but when I use this way it gives me a pop up blocked warning. How can I solve this?

Well, what happens when you press "Q" on the webpage in a normal browser? Also, "q" does not normally open a tab, so: why would you expect it to work? (Selenium uses a dedicated, clean profile when doing its job, it doesn't use "your Chrome" or whichever browser you told it to use, because that wouldn't make any sense for an integration testing framework)

This is related to the content of the web page. An a element on a web page can be triggered with the Q key, which opens a new tab. Therefore I want to press Q. The site does not allow me to select the link element with the selectors

I can actually handle this manually by saying allow pop ups in the site settings section from privacy and security, but it would be nice if there was a way to automate it...

we solve problems. Thank you very much

May be using of CSS identification of the target "Q" button will be useful. In that way you can identify the specific  "Q"  char

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
